# Translate code string into desc in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Here we have a hyphened string like `0-1-3`.... and the length is not fixed,
also we have a DETAIL table in hive to explain the meaning of each code.

`DETAIL 
| code | desc |
+ ---- + ---- +
| 0    | AAA  |
| 1    | BBB  |
| 2    | CCC  |
| 3    | DDD  |`

Now we need a hive query to convert the code string into a description string.

For example: the case `0-1-3` should get a string like `AAA-BBB-DDD`.

any advice on how to get that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` your string to get an array, `explode` array and join with detail table (CTE is used in my example instead of it, use normal table instead) to get desc joined with code. Then assemble string using `collect_list(desc)` to get an array + `concat_ws()` to get concatenated string:

```
select concat_ws('-',collect_list(d.desc)) as code_desc 
from
( --initial string explode
select explode(split('0-1-3','-')) as code
) s
inner join 
(-- use your table instead of this subquery
select 0  code, 'AAA' desc union all
select 1, 'BBB' desc union all
select 2, 'CCC' desc union all
select 3, 'DDD' desc
) d on s.code=d.code;
```

Result:

```
OK
AAA-BBB-DDD
Time taken: 114.798 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

In case you need to preserve the original order, then use `posexplode` it returns the element as well as its position in the original array. Then you can order by record ID and pos before `collect_list()`.

If your string is a table column then use lateral view to select exploded values.

This is more complicated example with order preserved and lateral view.

```
select str as original_string, concat_ws('-',collect_list(s.desc)) as transformed_string
from
(
select s.str, s.pos, d.desc     
from
( --initial string explode with ordering by str and pos
  --(better use your table PK, like ID instead of str for ordering), pos
select str, pos, code from ( --use your table instead of this subquery
                             select '0-1-3' as str union all
                             select '2-1-3' as str union all
                             select '3-2-1' as str
                           )s
lateral view outer posexplode(split(s.str,'-')) v as pos,code
) s
inner join 
(-- use your table instead of this subquery
select 0  code, 'AAA' desc union all
select 1, 'BBB' desc union all
select 2, 'CCC' desc union all
select 3, 'DDD' desc
) d on s.code=d.code
distribute by s.str -- this should be record PK candidate
sort by s.str, s.pos --sort on each reducer
)s
group by str;
```

Result:

```
OK
0-1-3   AAA-BBB-DDD
2-1-3   CCC-BBB-DDD
3-2-1   DDD-CCC-BBB
Time taken: 67.534 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Note that `distribute` + `sort` is being used instead of simply `order by str, pos`. distribute + sort works in fully distributed mode, `order by` will work also correct but on single reducer.

Comment: Thanks,great solution, but is there any way to ensure the result is in the same order of the original string

Comment: @Eric Added one more example with order preserved