# Parsing string in a hive table

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, explode

I have a hive table which has two columns (day, type_of_day) both of type string

```
"monday"    [{"temp" : 45, "weather": "rainny"}, {"temp" : 25, "weather": "sunny"}, {"temp" : 15, "weather": "storm"}]
"tuesday"   [{"temp" : 5, "weather": "winter"}, {"temp" : 10, "weather": "sun"}, {"temp" : 18, "weather": "dawn"}]
```

I wanna split ( I guess explode is the technical term) and then just get a list of weather for each day. I'm familiar with how to do this in python but is there a way to directly do this in hive.

```
"monday"    [45, 25, 15]
"tuesday"   [5, 10, 18]
```

Comment: Initial string also contains square brackets, but it is not array, it is string, right? I'm asking this because it is displayed like array. And you need output as array? or string "[45, 25, 15]" ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a string. I would prefer the output to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with your data example. Replace CTE with your table. Read comments in the code:

```
with your_table as (--use your table instead of this CTE
select stack(2,
             "monday",'[{"temp" : 45, "weather": "rainny"}, {"temp" : 25, "weather": "sunny"}, {"temp" : 15, "weather": "storm"}]',
             "tuesday" ,'[{"temp" : 5, "weather": "winter"}, {"temp" : 10, "weather": "sun"}, {"temp" : 18, "weather": "dawn"}]'
            )as (day, type_of_day)
) --use your table instead of this CTE


select s.day, array(get_json_object(type_of_day_array[0],'$.temp'),
                    get_json_object(type_of_day_array[1],'$.temp'),
                    get_json_object(type_of_day_array[2],'$.temp')
                   ) as result_array --extract JSON elements and construct array
 from
(
select day,  split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(type_of_day,'\\[|\\]',''),   --remove square brackets
                                  '\\}, *\\{','\\}##\\{'),                    --make convenient split separator
                   '##')                                                      --split                                  
          as type_of_day_array
  from your_table                                                             --use your table instead of this CTE
)s;
```

Result:

```
s.day   result_array    

monday  ["45","25","15"]    
tuesday ["5","10","18"]
```

If the array of JSON can contain more than three elements, then you can use [lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) explode or posexplode and then build the resulting array like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51570035/2700344.

Wrap array elements in cast(... as int) if you need `array<int>` as a result instead of `array<string>`:

```
cast(get_json_object(type_of_day[0],'$.temp') as int)...
```